# Differences in the hiring process between US and UK

Tags: interviewing, united-states, tech-industry

I have been looking at data science roles in the US, specifically in New York City. I am a data scientist in the UK with a master's degree from the UK and 5+ yrs work experience at a well-known UK company.

I would like to start applying for some roles and I just wanted to understand what differences can I expect between the hiring processes for technical roles in the UK and the US.

What are also some concerns US recruiters have based on my UK work experience and anything I can do to prepare for addressing them? I have previously been told that being from Europe, the work ethic and expectations may differ and therefore I may be at a disadvantage as opposed to a US candidate.

No need for visa sponsorship in my scenario.

Comment: Do you have permission to work in the US?

Comment: The biggest concern would be, are you currently authorized to work in the U.S. If yor answer is no, most potential employers will stop right there, because getting a work visa is very painful, expensive, and uncertain. Also, an increasing number of large U.S. employers request some form of a Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion (DEI) Statement as part of application from everyone - even data scientists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As someone who has worked both in the UK and Canada, let me tell you what I know. The US is not noticeably different from Canada. However it's been 30 years since I worked in the UK, so some of the changes might be due to time rather than geography.

The hiring process isn't significantly different, except that you send a "resume" instead of a "CV". It's the same thing, different name. All applications are of course online. Normally you are expected to upload your resume online, and then separately fill in all the information from the resume on an online form. You won't get any sort of communication with the firm unless they want to talk to you. If you are lucky you will get an automated response that they received your resume.

The main differences are in conditions of work. In the US you can be fired for absolutely anything with no recourse or payment. You can almost always be made to work excessive hours (compared with the UK). Overtime payments don't exist. Make sure you ask about it, and check with review sites about how often it actually happens. Two weeks vacation is standard - maybe three when you reach a senior level. Remember health care is paid for by employers, not by the government. Make sure you get details of what is covered and what you have to pay to get it before you accept a job. Also make sure you are getting *a lot* higher salary than you would expect in the UK. That will compensate you for the much larger amount of work that is going to be expected of you. The larger salary is normal, but you will have to ask for it. If you ask for the same salary you got in the UK, they will happily pay it and let you take the hit. Don't forget to make sure that your benefits and conditions of work are spelled out in writing.

The point to the hiring process is that all of those things are things you must ask about in interview. Don't assume a forty hour week. Don't assume four weeks vacation. Don't assume full healthcare coverage is provided, even for professional jobs. Check out the reputation of the company before you interview, and run away from anything with a poor rating.

In the tech industry your UK qualifications and experience will be taken at face value. One thing to beware of is that most reputable degrees in the US take four years. If your UK degree took three years, then make sure you emphasize "four year degree equivalent". If you got an honours degree make sure the resume says says "with honours". US degrees are normally rated by "GPA". You will have to give them an idea of what your degree class means - something like "graduated in the top 10%" will usually work.

Comment: I would add that in the US you don't always get an actual work contract (that would spell out all the import aspects you mentioned in legal language) but only an offer letter. So you have to be extra careful that the nice things they told you verbally are also written down somewhere because otherwise you are not getting them.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments ,these are good things to keep an eye out for and no website tells you this. Very helpful, do add more tips if you have them.

Comment: Assume there will be no sick pay or time off in lieu for working on weekends or public holidays, no employment or maternity protection you get in the UK and/or Europe. They can also reduce what they pay you at whim unless it is in your limited contract of employment. Plus, your accommodation costs will be even more than in the UK even.

If I were you I would be looking for work in Europe - Netherlands, Ireland or  where a lot of English is spoken. Australia or New Zealand even - data scientists are in short supply & you will be welcomed with open arms.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any systematic difference in the *process* per se. There are differences in work visa requirements and tax handling, obviously, and those may constitute enough additional hassle for the company to put you at a disadvantage compared to an in-country/citizen applicant. It's up to you to be a compelling enough candidate to overcome that.